# Why doesn't Focused Charge stun? (Templar Aedric Spear ability)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

The Templar Aedric Spear ability, Focused Charge, has the following description:

"Charge to target, interrupting casts and stuns them for 3 seconds."

When I use this ability, it never stuns my target. I haven't yet found an opportunity to use it against a casting target since the majority of spells in ESO are instant casts. Does the stun happen only if an interrupt occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears according to [this thread](http://forums.elderscrollsonline.com/discussion/79002/toppling-charge-templar-charge-ability-not-working-as-intended) that you are not the only one experiencing this issue.

I dug a little deeper and found [this thread](http://tamrielfoundry.com/topic/templar-focused-charge-stun/) that clearly states the only way this stun works is if you hit someone mid-cast.

The wording in the description is a bit vague but, if you read it, it does clearly state **interrupting casts**.

Comment: Yep, you're right.